# How critical is the position of the shifting aids (pins) on the front chainring?

Tags: crankset, chainring, shifting

My crankset (Ritchey Logic) has a 5 arm spider design with one chainring bolt hidden behind the crank arm. When installing a large chainring I need to rotate the ring in order to install it properly. Because of this, the shifting aids are now also rotated compared to a traditional crankset. How does this influence shifting quality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a universal answer to this because different manufacturers do their tooth profiles and shift aids differently.

However, it's easy to imagine that since a major design goal of a ramped chainring is to facilitate shifting under load or with poor technique, they're going to clock some aspects of the design relative to the power stroke. (Or really power strokes, since riders can be left- or right-leg dominant.)

If you had perfectly evenly applied power all through the crank rotation, it shouldn't make much difference (even then you do have gravity playing some kind of none-zero role). But a human doesn't do that, so I would guess that on average it would make shifting under load worse.

Hidden fifth arm cranks also need the drop pin clocked in line with the hole, not between. Sugino made the Ritchey cranks and has also had a number of hidden fifth arm cranks in their own line, so that would be a good place to look for a replacement where everything just works.

Answer (score 2):

Aaah, you mean because the chainrings are rotated 30° relative to the crankarms compared to a traditional crankset?

Since the chainrings themselves are still aligned to each other and you are not supposed to shift under load (i.e. the position of the shifting aids relative to the pedal stroke doesn’t matter) I don’t think it will make a difference.